# Invert electric motor rotation

Tags: electrical, electric-motor

I got this Bergin AC motor which was from a pool pump, but now I want to use it to power a saw.

For this I need to invert its rotation direction. How can I do that by just switching wires?

The four cables at the top just go to the power switch. Unfortunately the metal housing can not be opnened.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add Make and Model number of motor to the question please. Appears to be capacitance run motor (White Tube at top of picture).

Comment: @FiascoLabs i have added a photo of the label.

Comment: Can you take off the connection housing (2 to 4 screws securing it) and post a photo?  Let us see the other end of where that pink tubing goes.

Comment: @wallyk: both of the pink cables go into the dark red tube. but ill take a better photo.

Comment: Where does the connector with the blue, brown, red, and black wires lead?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: that is just the on/off switch.

Comment: Alright then.  One more thing -- is there electrical continuity between the red wire going to the capacitor (tubular thing) and the red wire going to the on/off switch?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: that is hard to find out, cause i would need to find the other end of the dark red tube. but for that i would need break open the metal housing of the motor itself.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?  (A cheap one will suffice for this application, even.)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: yes i do, which wire combination should i measure?

Comment: Put your meter on continuity (or the lowest ohms range if it does not have a continuity function), pull the two red wires off their terminals, and measure between the two.  If you measure a value of a couple ohms or less (and/or your meter beeps), they're connected.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sorry for the late reply. so measuring the resistance of the two red wires measures about 0.2 ohms. so i would say they are connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single phase, permanent-split-capacitor (capacitor run) motors, like your unit, are normally reversed by switching the roles of the start and run windings.  Unfortunately, with the way your unit is wired, it is not possible to make the necessary wiring changes without completely disassembling the motor -- you would have to disconnect the two red wires from each other, then connect the red wire from inside the motor to the terminal that now has the tan wire from the motor on it while connecting the red wire from the capacitor and the tan wire from the motor together, then taking them to where the red wire from the motor now leads.

So, you'll have to head down to a shop that sells motors (industrial-supply places will have them, guaranteed) and get a new motor to power your saw with; either that, or find a way to make your saw work with a motor that rotates the opposite direction from the original.